# Polling Accurev SCM only if there are any changes in code

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, accurev

I am polling Accurev SCM after every 30 minutes using 
Poll SCM as H/30 * * * *

However, I want to change the functionality so that Accurev is polled by Jenkins only after there are changes in code in Accurev. I don't want to keep polling Accurev SCM after every 30 minutes

Please let me know how that can be achieved.

Comment: You do realize that the SCM polling is how Jenkins knows your repository changed?  You're effectively asking if there is a way to only check if a change happened once you know for sure that a change has occurred.  If you could do this why poll at all, just start the job.

Comment: Actually, I want to start the job everytime a change occurs.

Comment: Are you using this plugin [AccuRev Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3309595)?  If so the simple answer would be to poll with a much much shorter frequency than you are.  After some quick reading on that plugin I don't think that functionality exists currently. It hasn't been updated since 2014.  You might be able to fork it on Git and write your own method that allows a trigger on SCM change.  That would probably involve setting up something that pushes a notification to the plugin though.

Comment: Yes, I am using AccuRev plugin. Can you throw some light on how    `to fork it on Git and write your own method that allows a trigger on SCM change. That would probably involve setting up something that pushes a notification to the plugin though`

Comment: Not much really, I'm not particularly familiar with Java (you'd need to write some code to do this) and this could be a terrible approach, but:  Here is the [git repo](https://github.com/jenkinsci/accurev-plugin) You'll want to do a pull request to get the source code of the plugin and then add a method that listens (perhaps with TCP/IP?) for some sort of notification and starts the job.  You'll then have to see if the AccuRev repo can send a notification. If it can you'll want to figure out it's structure and write your method in the plugin to parse that notification correctly.  1/2

Comment: It would take much more time (and knowledge, given my lack of Java experience) than I can spare to actually do this but that's a high level description of what would need to be done.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AccuRev triggers to call the build of your Jenkins job. If you set a server-side trigger, like `server-post-promote-trig` [(documentation)](http://supportline.microfocus.com/Documentation/books/AccuRev/AccuRev/6.2/webhelp/AccuRev_Admin/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=trig_param_file.html#1004508), AccuRev will execute a task every time a change is promoted to a certain stream.

The only thing you need to code in that trigger will be a call to `http://your_jenkins_server/job/your_job/build` and Jenkins will execute the job immediately, so you don't need to select any checkbox under the "Build Triggers" section.